# Hausdorff dimension of graphs of one-dimensional Brownian motion

Tags: probability, fractals, brownian-motion

First question here, my apologies if it is a duplicate or inappropriate.

There is a [page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_fractals_by_Hausdorff_dimension) on Wikipedia listing fractals by Hausdorff dimension and it includes the graph of a "regular Brownian function" as having Hausdorff dimension 1.5. Does this mean that a Brownian motion has Hausdorff dimension almost always, or is it the expected value, or something else?

I've tried to look for references (besides the Wikipedia one that I can't get) and googling for more information to little avail.

If it's not true that the graph of a Brownian motion has Hausdorff dimension 1.5 almost always, is it true that the Hausdorff dimension >1 almost always?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the Hausdorff dimension of the graph is 3/2 almost surely. 
A good explanation can be found in Chapter 4 of Peres and Morters's 
[book on Brownian motion](https://people.bath.ac.uk/maspm/book.pdf). See Theorem 4.29 on page 110.

Comment: Thanks! I actually found that book, but just searching for "Hausdorff dimension" didn't bring up the theorem. I should be more thorough in my skimming.

Comment: @minimalrho Glad to be of help!

Comment: book is no longer available, it would be useful if someone would update the answer for good explanation

Comment: The url has been updated.